# custom filesystem with fancy readdir or bash completion behaviour

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

Ok. After trying to formulate this question a couple of times, it turns out that this will be a long one. Anywho:

Consider this file structure:

```
photos/ 
  ants/ 
    pic1.jpg
  animals/ 
    dog.png
  profile_pic.jpg
```

if you do

```
cd photos
ls
```

you get

```
ants/    animals/    profile_pic.jpg
```

However since the directories vacation and animals only contain one file each, it could arguably be more useful to get

```
ants/pic1.jpg    ani../dog.png    profile_pic.jpg
```

directly, as opposed to having to visit each of animals and vacation. On tab completion however, as in cd a you would want suggestions of the directories instead.

So I know bash completion is handled by the /etc/bash_completion script (I don't wanna go there) and the readline library, but this doesn't really affect ls and certainly doesn't help if you want to extend functionality to file managers such a nautilus. Therefore I was hoping some of this could be tackled using a custom filesystem over fuse. A initial investigation based on [this tutorial](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/fuse-tutorial/) was somewhat depressing though, as the fuse file system seems to in no way differentiate between my different use cases (readdir, opendir, releasedir every time).

To formulate a question: In what way could a similar functionality be approached, if it's even possible without major revision in the kernel? Where should I look for more information?

Thanks for you time!

EDIT: To clarify, bash is a useful example, but in the end I want this to be the same through nautilus and every other program accessing the files, and I'm gonna write a file system anyway for other issues.

Comment: This will obviously break some programs.

Comment: Some things are better left in user space, such as `ls -R`, or `find`. How do you know someone else doesn't want to see only the directoryies?

Comment: @BatchyX You are of course right. There will definitely be issues.

Comment: @Keith So the problem I'm experiencing is that the FUSE API doesn't seem to support reading subsets of a directory. The entire thing is always read, and filtering is done by the program. This is robust, but limits what you can do with a fuse-based file system. Don't missunderstand: the design is good for it's intended usage, but I'm almost outside this usage =).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to write a bash script to do this for you. I'm fairly certain you are not going to want to code this into the Kernel or Filesystem :)

Logic like this should work:

Descend into directories... Check if one file ... print folder/file... else print top folder

Comment: I see what you mean, but this is not actually functionality that I want only in bash, but globally. Clarified the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I cannot post a comment, so I have to write an "answer" (I still don't understand this decision, but enough of the ranting). Since you've already discarded the `bash`option and hinted towards a `FUSE`solution, I'd like to give you a couple of "more or less viable" ideas while you implement your `mp3fs`:

- **Enhancing** `struct stat` with a new type, let's say `st_nfiles`. Each time you `create()/symlink()/hardlink()` a file, you will be updating this entry in the respective `FUSE` operations. Figuring out if there is only one entry in the referred directory, will then merely be a lookup and comparison of `(struct stat) dirp->st_nfiles` with 1. You would  need to `LD_PRELOAD` a library to your user space that hijacks and extends the necessary `printf` calls to output the `stat` results with this change.
- **Misusing** the existing `(struct stat) dirp->st_nlink` in your `FUSE` operations code of `getattr()`. The drawback could be issues with tools that depend on `st_nlink`; if I remember correctly, `find`is one of them. This also needs a global `LD_PRELOAD` library to fiddle with the output.
- **On the fly parsing** in the `FUSE` operations code of `getattr()`, similar to what you would do in pure userspace. [This](http://pastebin.com/7AqWa5X5) code snippet should give you the idea.

Not sure if this is want you wanted. I wished I could have added this as a comment, rather than a half-backed answer. Maybe you want to remove the `bash` tag from this question, since you've indicated that this won't suitable for you, since you want tools like `nautilus` to behave the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm learning stuff again =). I wasn't actually familiar with the `LD_PRELOAD` trick (not frequent c user), but that might prove really useful. In the end the problem still seems to be that when doing `cd` i want the directory from `readdir`, but when doing `ls` listing i want the file. Tricky!